# Using a non npm 3rd party library with Ionic / Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angularjs-3rd-party

Up until now, any 3rd party library I have worked with in my Ionic / Angular project has been available as an npm install and everything has been pretty straightforward.

I’m now trying to utilise this library on a payment form:

http://docs.pay360.com/cardlock/using-the-library/

and I’m really not sure how to do this on my payments component i.e the bit in step 3 - including the library and invoking it ?

Does anyone have any guidance on what I would need to do here?  I assume I add the tag to my index.html to import the library but I'm not sure how the library would then be imported in my component?

Comment: This may help: [Reference external javascript library in html files with angular cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47687027/reference-external-javascript-library-in-html-files-with-angular-cli)

Comment: I may have worked it out - now testing.